# difference between glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate and 3-phosphoglycerate

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbohydrates, organophosphorus-compounds

In the photosynthetic dark reaction there are two types of reactions: light-dependent and light-independent.  In the light-independent reactions during reduction 3-phosphoglycerate is converted to glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate.  I don't find any difference between them because both have a 3 carbon chain attached to a phosphate group. Can you please clear it up for me because my book says that the latter one is a sugar.  Why isn't the first one sugar too?

Answer (score 7):

The difference between the two molecules is highlighted in red.

[image]

The functional group in 3-phosphoglycerate is a *carboxylic acid*. That in glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate is an *aldehyde*.

Sugars have the general formula $\ce{C_$n$H_{$2n$}O_$n$}$. To accomplish this specific ratio of carbon to hydrogen to oxygen, the requirement is that one of the carbons must have a carbonyl group (i.e. forms an aldehyde or ketone), whereas the remainder of the carbons have one hydroxyl group each. For example, the open-chain structure of glucose is:

[image]

The carbonyl group is in red and the hydroxyl groups are in blue.

Therefore, glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate is simply a phosphorylated sugar: C-1 is the aldehydic carbon and C-2 and C-3 have hydroxyl groups, the latter of which is phosphorylated.

3-Phosphoglycerate is one oxidation state too high.

Comment: Which makes 3-phosphoglycerate an aldonic acid ;)